# Parsing a mod rewrite enviorement variable

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a huge list of referers for specific URLs to do redirects for.  I want to do this with a Map file by having the referrer as the search and the URL+Destination as second URL.  So if the mod rewrite file looks like this
Referer  /pages/index.html+/pages2/index2.html

I can set Map result to a search variable that will return the URL+Destination
RewriteRule . - [E=SEARCH:${ReferMap:%{REFERER}|NOT-FOUND}]

Is there a way I can parse this variable at the "+" sign and set a variable with values /pages/index.html  and /pages2/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following (not tested), after your assignment to SEARCH :

```
 RewriteCond %{ENV:SEARCH} !NOT-FOUND
 RewriteCond %{ENV:SEARCH} ^([^+]*)
 RewriteCond %{ENV:SEARCH} [+](.*)
 RewriteRule %1 %2 [L]
```